# NuGet Package Manager windows not opening

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2015

With Visual Studio 2015 RTM, NuGet Package Manager 3.0 crashes whenever I try to rebuild my application, which is under TFS source control. It also won't open the NuGet Package Manager configuration window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be the same issue I encountered. It is a known issue with the version of nuget packaged with VS2015 RTM.

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/974

> csharpfritz commented 3 days ago
>
> A hotfix is now available to install and we are confident it will
>   unblock you. Please grab the install from one of these locations
>   appropriately:
>
> 2.8.7 for VS 2013: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/releases/download/2.8.7/NuGet.Tools.vsix
>
> 3.1.1 for VS 2015: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/releases/download/3.1.1/NuGet.Tools.vsix
>
> We will publish these to the Visual Studio gallery next week.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug with version 3.0, where it cannot check-out a solution's `NuGet.Config` file properly. The way to handle this is to manually check the file out for edit.